# How remove some string in database file

Tags: sql, string

I have too many link in my database that need remove some string in them. 
like following link :

> example.com/gallery/images/53637678653059406553.gif.pagespeed.ce.zHxD2y5wHz.gif

I need remove all content after first gif or jpeg or png. (.pagespeed.ce.zHxD2y5wHz.gif) anybody have idea to help me ?

Comment: Which database you are using?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can try like this:

```
LEFT(yourValue, CHARINDEX('gif', yourValue) - 1)
```

In MYSQL

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(yourValue, 'gif', 1)
```

Comment: 2 comments: it should search for `.gif` instead of `gif`. We also want to keep that part, so we'll want to `+ 2` instead of `- 1` (or `+ 3` with the `.`).  So: `SELECT LEFT(yourValue, CHARINDEX('.gif',yourValue) + 3)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm expanding on Rahul Tripathi's answer.  It works fine for `.gif`, but we don't know the file extension being used.  I'd suggest searching for the second `.` and cutting it off there.

*Samples below in MS SQL format*

Finding the location of the first `.`:

```
CHARINDEX('.', yourValue)
```

Getting everything (or at least the next 10 characters) after that `.`:

```
SUBSTRING(yourValue, CHARINDEX('.', yourValue) + 1, 10)
```

Finding the location of the next `.` in that sub-string:

```
CHARINDEX('.',SUBSTRING(yourValue, CHARINDEX('.', yourValue) + 1, 10))
```

Add the two locations to find the location of the second `.` in the whole string:

```
CHARINDEX('.', yourValue) + CHARINDEX('.', SUBSTRING(yourValue, CHARINDEX('.', yourValue) + 1, 10))
```

Keeping only the data up to that second `.`:

```
LEFT(yourValue, CHARINDEX('.', yourValue) + CHARINDEX('.', SUBSTRING(yourValue, CHARINDEX('.', yourValue) + 1, 10)) - 1)
```

Note that there still may be issues depending on the data.  If there is no second `.`, it will cut off the `.gif`, and if there are no `.` at all, it will error out.